# How to get value of button from Button Group element in React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, buttongroup

I am trying to get the value of button in each question and want to store the data. For that, I am using handleClick on Button Group to get the value of button and changing the state in state object by setting setState() but I am not getting undefined output. Can anyone tell If I am using correct method to get value of button from ButtonGroup.

code ::

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CommonButton from "../Button/CommonButton";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

class Section extends Component {
  // questions = [
  //   { question1: "I was stressed with my nerves on edge" },
  //   { question: "I lost hope and wanted to give up when something went wrong" },
  //   { question: "I feel very satisfied with the way I look and act" }
  // ];

  state = {
    que1: "",
    que2: "",
    que3: ""
  };

  handleClick = event => {
    console.log(
      this.setState({
        que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
      })
    );
  };

  handleClick2 = event => {
    console.log(
      this.setState({
        que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key2").value
      })
    );
  };

  handleClick3 = event => {
    console.log(
      this.setState({
        que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key3").value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <p>1. I was stressed with my nerves on edge.</p>
        <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Button data-key="Never">Never</Button>
          <Button data-key="Occassionally">Occassionally</Button>
          <Button data-key="Often">Often</Button>
          <Button data-key="Very Often">Very Often</Button>
          <Button data-key="Always">Always</Button>
        </Button.Group>
        <span />
        <p>2. I lost hope and wanted to give up when something went wrong.</p>
        <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick2}>
          <Button data-key2="Never">Never</Button>
          <Button data-key2="Occassionally">Occassionally</Button>
          <Button data-key2="Often">Often</Button>
          <Button data-key2="Very Often">Very Often</Button>
          <Button data-key2="Always">Always</Button>
        </Button.Group>
        <p>3. I feel very satisfied with the way I look and act</p>
        <Button.Group widths="5" onClick={this.handleClick3}>
          <Button data-key3="Never">Never</Button>
          <Button data-key3="Occassionally">Occassionally</Button>
          <Button data-key3="Often">Often</Button>
          <Button data-key3="Very Often">Very Often</Button>
          <Button data-key3="Always">Always</Button>
        </Button.Group>
        <p />
        <Link to="/section2">
          <CommonButton text={"NEXT"} />{" "}
        </Link>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Section;
```

Input :: [image]

output :: undefined

Comment: `setState` does not return a value, so you can't print the result of it. You'd have to add a callback to it, which would print the actual state value.

Comment: Is it correct way to handle click for each ButtonGroup ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `ButtonGroup` but as long as it is correctly targeting the element you clicked on, then it should be fine.

Comment: ok thanks for reply....

Answer (score 0):

you are print this.setState

change this

```
console.log(
      this.setState({
        que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key3").value
      })
    );
```

to

```
      this.setState({
        que2: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key3").value
      },()=>{
 console.log(this.state.que2)
})
```

Comment: can you create sandbox here?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/9ywqvonwm4
output :Never 
Occassionally 
Often 
Very Often 
Always

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to log `state` but instead you are doing console.log of `this.setState()` function. As setState do not return anything, output is undefined. In handler function just change

```
console.log(
  this.setState({
    que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
  })
);
```

to

```
 this.setState({
   que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
 })
this.forceUpdate();
console.log(this.state.que1);
```

or better solution is to use callback of setState -

```
this.setState({que1: event.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.que1);
})
```